# In Excel for Mac 2011 how do I format an entire row based on the value in one cell in that row?

Tags: excel, osx-mavericks, conditional-formatting

This question has been asked before but the answers are not for Excel for Mac 2011.
I will try to make the question as clear as possible.

I wish to highlight an entire row based on the value in just one cell of that row.
Concretely, if the cell in column B = Active, then I wish to format the whole row as Boldface.
If the cell in column B = Inactive, then I want to leave the row alone.

The other answers to this all have screenshots of Excel for Windows but that doesn't help at all.

e.g. Cell B2 = Active. So I want the whole row 2 to be Boldface. Cell B3 = Inactive, so I want row 3 to be left alone. 
I'm quite stupid when it comes to Excel. Please explain it to me like I'm a four year old.

I tried to add a screen shot but Stackoverflow says I "need at least 10 reputation to post images."

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to apply conditional formatting based on a formula?

Select whole range of data starting at row 1and then apply this formula in conditional formatting

=$B1="Active"

Apply required format

Note the $ - that's essential to format entire row